# TypeError: the first argument must be callable when I import a scheduler in my views.py file of django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

I am using Django 1.11. I want to use the scheduler in my application to run my script once in a day.

This is my view.py file

```
from __future__ import print_function
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from django.http import HttpResponse
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import requests
import schedule
import time


def republic(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Success Hindustan</h1>")


def indiatv(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Success Hindustan</h1>")

def ndtv(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Success NDTV</h1>")


schedule.every().day.at("17:19").do(republic(requests))
schedule.every().day.at("17:19").do(indiatv(requests))
schedule.every().day.at("17:19").do(ndtv(requests))

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

When I run the server I am getting following error

```
 File "/home/imsaiful/PiroProject/pironews/feed/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/home/imsaiful/PiroProject/pironews/feed/views.py", line 230, in <module>
    schedule.every().day.at("17:19").do(republic(requests))
  File "/home/imsaiful/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/schedule/__init__.py", line 385, in do
    self.job_func = functools.partial(job_func, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: the first argument must be callable
```

But when I remove the scheduler lines then the application running properly.

Comment: It should be `do(republic, requests)`, not `do(republic(request))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Fixing the scheduling call

By writing:

```
schedule.every().day.at("17:19").do(republic(requests))
schedule.every().day.at("17:19").do(republic(requests))
schedule.every().day.at("17:19").do(republic(requests))
```

You schedule the *result* of the `republic(request)` as job, not "*calling `republic` with `requests` as job*".

The [**`do(job_func, *args, **kwargs)`** [schedule-doc]](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#schedule.Job.do) function however allows to provide parameters, you provide these *after* a reference to the job, so:

```
schedule.every().day.at("17:19").do(republic, requests)
schedule.every().day.at("17:19").do(republic, requests)
schedule.every().day.at("17:19").do(republic, requests)
```

## Running the scheduler in a specific thread

You can not run the scheduler this way in Django, since it will mean that you keep running the command when *loading* the file. So loading the file will never terminate, and hence the server will never start.

You can run the scheduler asynchronous however, with:

```
from threading import Thread
from __future__ import print_function
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from django.http import HttpResponse
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import requests
import schedule
import time


def republic(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Success Hindustan</h1>")

schedule.every().day.at("17:19").do(republic, requests)
schedule.every().day.at("17:19").do(republic, requests)
schedule.every().day.at("17:19").do(republic, requests)

class SchedulerThread(Thread):
     @classmethod
     def run(cls):
         while True:
             schedule.run_pending()
             time.sleep(interval)

ScheduleThread().start()
```

Finally note that `requests` is *not* a `HttpRequest` object, so you should not write your functions as views, but as "vanilla" functions that perform certain work.

Comment: When I do like this "schedule.every().day.at("17:19").do(republic, requests)" then my server is not starting. It is just showing this in the terminal Performing system checks...
But when I try to like this "schedule.every().day.at("17:19").do(republic(requests))" as mention in the question the server start but giving that error.

Comment: Well the idea is that you specified that the function is only called at specific times (each day at `17:19`, so it is normal that it is not running, Furthermore the `while 1` indeed prevents the server from starting. You should run this asnychronous.

Comment: This is the URL of my project http://trendinganalytica.com/ Basically I am trying to fetch the news by web scrapping. So, I use the scheduler to fetch the news daily automatically. I need to analyze the news for my academic projects. This is the link of views.py file https://github.com/imsaiful/piro/blob/master/pironews/feed/views.py . So, kindly help me what should I need to do.

Comment: The type error "typeerror the first argument must be callable" has been resolved and you also got the eight. The server starts at specified the time in day.at() and then while 1 is preventing the server from running. So , as you told me to run this asynchronously.So i add your following colde like this 
class ScheduleThread(object):
    @classmethod
    def run(cls):
        while True:
            schedule.run_pending()
            time.sleep(10)


ScheduleThread().start()   But when I now start the server I got this error 'ScheduleThread' object has no attribute 'start'

Comment: You should use `Thread` from the `threading` module (like specified in the head).

Comment: Done! Thanks. Replace object by Thread. Now, will this run when the server is stopped?

Comment: @imsaiful: no. If you want that, you should work with celery, or a cronjob.

Comment: I will update this on amazon EC2 that sever will be running 24*7. So will this run daily at specify time as I want to fetch news on daily basis.

Comment: If the server runs, then this should normally work yes.

Comment: Ok, I will try this in my production server today and will update you. Thanks a ton Sir. You always angel to me.

Comment: Working in production as I want. Thanks Sir.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179466/discussion-between-imsaiful-and-willem-van-onsem).

Answer (score 4):

> republic(requests) will return HttpResponse,

so the execution would be

```
schedule.every().day.at("17:19").do(HttpResponse)
```

inside `do` method you should mention function, not class instance.
you can use one of the below

solution 1:

```
schedule.every().day.at("17:19").do(lambda: republic(requests))
```

solution 2.

```
schedule.every().day.at("17:19").do(republic, requests)
```

solution 3.

```
import functools
schedule.every().day.at("17:19").do(functools.partial(republic, requests))
```

Comment: I think what is missing here is a *solution* to the problem. Please provide one, and I will upvote :)

Answer (score 2):

based on the [schedule.Job.do](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#schedule.Job.do), you should pass args after the function:

```
schedule.every().day.at("17:19").do(republic, requests)
schedule.every().day.at("17:19").do(indiatv, requests)
schedule.every().day.at("17:19").do(ndtv, requests)
```

> do(job_func, *args, **kwargs)
>
> Specifies the job_func that should be called every time the job runs.
>   Any additional arguments are passed on to job_func when the job runs.

Comment: When I do like this "schedule.every().day.at("17:19").do(republic, requests)" then my server is not starting. It is just showing this in the terminal Performing system checks... But when I try to like this "schedule.every().day.at("17:19").do(republic(requests))" as mention in the question the server start but giving that error.